Is "a round" a round object or a round shape?
An object and the the shape of an object are different.
An object has several properties, such as shape, weight, texture, and function.
Shape describes the outline or the form an object takes in space.
So, a shape is just one character of an object.
Anh, if you look at the cup, its shape might be cylindrical, but the cup itself is more than just its shape. It also has other features like its material, color, and the fact that it can hold things.
Now, Is "a round" a round object or a round shape?
Britannica says

round [count]: a round shape
Cut the carrots into rounds. [=round slices]
a round [=wheel] of cheese

Oxford says

round: a round object or piece of something
Cut the pastry into rounds.

Do you say "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into rounds" or "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into round shapes"?
I think we can say "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into round shapes".
However, if "a round" is a round object, then you can not say "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into rounds" right?
But if "a round" is a round shape, can you say "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into rounds"?
Also, which are correct?
"She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into squares" or "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into square shapes" ?
"She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into ovals" or "She shaped/filed/cut her fingernails into oval shapes" ?

"Round" as a noun always refers to a circular object AFAIA, never a round side of something larger. I can't think of an especially elegant way to say this, but I also wouldn't normally see the need to specify that fingernails are round… as opposed to what? Squared-off designer nails? Claws?

@the-baby-is-you, but the dictionary (Britannica) says "a round= a round shape". Do you want to reject it?

Well the logical next point of debate is the definition of "shape." There are many, at least one of which supports my interpretation, and yes, I believe that's what the dictionary meant (albeit it could be clearer). I've never heard anyone call a rounded edge of something "a round."

@the-baby-is-you, in the nail care world, a round fingernail does not mean the whole nail is round but just the tip. We can just change "to shape the fingernail tip into a round" for clarity. I guess you are British and British grammar is stricter than American one. British people might distinguish "round"  and "rounded".

I'm American. A fingernail can be "round," it just can't be "a round," as a noun.

@the-baby-is-you, in American English, a round is also "a round shape" not just a round object https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/round

This conversation is going in circles. You now have multiple native English speakers in agreement that fingernails cannot be rounds. Are you going to listen to the community you solicited opinions from or ignore it?

Lady here. You can ask for pointy, almost dagger-like, nails; almond-shaped, square-tipped nails; rounded (round shape), and oval nails. You do not ask the nail technician to cut your nails into rounds unless you want your finger tips to be sawed off.

Look how many results I found for "shaped her fingernails round" … one when searching for a string of words, you have to enclose them in speech marks.

@Mari-LouA, This is the title of a youtube video "Shaping your nail into an Oval or Round" (video: youtube.com/watch?v=qM__9SQeEuU) What do you think about it?

She says "how to file your nail from either a square or a  squoval, into a round [shape] or square shape"— "a round shape" is OK. How do I file my nails into a squoval shape?

@Mari-LouA, Then her title got wrong then. Also, in American English, a round is also "a round shape" not just a round object. britannica.com/dictionary/round . If you are right, the the dictionary is wrong or it has a wrong definition.

It's ellipsis "For my birthday make me a red or a  yellow sponge cake" you don't  have to repeat the noun phrase twice, e.g  "... make me a red sponge cake or a yellow sponge cake" The YouTube title: Shaping your nail into an Oval or Round Both oval and round are shapes, the word "shape" is implied. So what about the link I posted about squoval from a British website? What about the google search results for  "shaped her fingernails round" … ? Did you see the number of hits for that? Are you going to conveniently ignore those too?

Do you at least agree that cutting nails into rounds is neither idiomatic or logical?

@Mari-LouA, Of course, I am aware of  "shaped her fingernails round" ... But, you are the one who ignored the definition from the American dictionary. You did not dare to say the dictionary is wrong or maybe you are British, you don't dare to speak for American speakers.

So "cutting pastry (or carrots) into rounds" means you can "cut fingernails into rounds"?!? The dictionary definitions are correct, I never said they weren't but you can't apply them to fingernails. For example, "trim the fat off meat" you can trim your fingernails but you don't trim the nails off (your) fingers that's not idiomatic. "Cut the meat into rounds to make meatballs?" No. You shape the ground/minced meat into balls

And for the third and last time  when you claimed you found many results for "shaped her fingernails round" why didn't you post the link? I only found one hit on Google, and it's from your question. You still don't want to admit that "cutting fingernails into rounds" was a bad guess. You can't say people say it, because if you do find one example, it's will be one among thousands or even millions of hits where native speakers say it differently.

I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on in the comments. @Tom, did your questions get answered, or if there's questions that you still have maybe you can edit the question and explain more?

@Mari-LouA, I understood you perfectly well but you don't understand me. What I mean is that the definition of the dictionary (Britannica) says "a round= a round shape". So, I thought instead of saying "I shaped my fingernail into a round shape" (this sentence is correct), we can say "I shaped my fingernail into a round" (which is wrong) because the definition says "a round= a round shape". You said the dictionary (Britannica) is right?? Then why "a round = a round shape".

@Mari-LouA, I updated my question, which is quite different from the old one.

No, to "cut someting into rounds" is like the carrots example. Discrete round pieces.

She rounded her fingernails with a file.

See the (transitive) verb round.

This video title is "How to shape your nails into a square." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOJcWoFwjVo

They say "To shape your nails into a beautiful round shape" in this article https://www.ellamila.com/blogs/articles/guide-to-perfect-nail-shape?srsltid=AfmBOoondEa5R89ne1EE7blAUqkbLmyWHz0N86U2RGof-W-JPAX3NehD

@Tom, I don't really care what the video shows and didn't watch it. I'm telling you how to use the verb round in the context of shaping something with a file.  And to be truly idiomatic, that article should say "rounded" shape, not "round shape".

But "round" is also an adjective like "a round table" https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/round#

Here they say "Shaping your nail into an Oval or Round" (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qM__9SQeEuU)

Fingernail maintenance in the English-speaking world is an industry largely staffed by non-native English speakers. "Cutting nails into rounds" definitely sounds wrong to a native speaker, but some other variations are more plausible ("cut the nails round" maybe). But if you're seriously interested in beauty industry language, you shouldn't ask here; we can only tell you what sounds reasonable to an average English speaker with no professional expertise.

@Tom  But fingernails are not round as a table is round. They are rounded, though  there are no doubt some native English speakers who would say "I want my fingernails round not square".  That could be because they're simplifying so a non-native speaker will understand them more easily; or it could be because they speak the language only as well as they do. Speaking is really no different from, say, running, when viewed from a certain perspective: the human being knows how to do it but some do it more fluently than others.

When I was small, my grandmother said she was going to buy me a pair of scissors with round ends so I couldn't poke myself with sharp points. I was puzzled because I thought of round  as meaning spherical, and I couldn't imagine what  these scissors would look like!

@KateBunting  I do believe there should be a safety scissors with a globe at each tip, as child-Kate invented.  Here is a 2D realization.  https://www.amazon.com/Camila-Solingen-Professional-Nostril-Scissors/dp/B00HDOY33G/ref=asc_df_B00HDOY33G/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=692875362841&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17102950567488602395&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9007262&hvtargid=pla-2281435180458&mcid=51d56fd472de30659b383cb4f65b3d5a&hvocijid=17102950567488602395-B00HDOY33G-&hvexpln=73&th=1

@TimR , in the nail care world, a round fingernail does not mean the whole nail is round but just the tip. We can just change "to shape the fingernail tip into a round" for clarity. I guess you are British and British grammar is stricter than American one. British people might distinguish "round"  and "rounded". Most videos on Youtube from people of the USA and they say "round fingernails". British people sometimes say American people using wrong grammar. Similarly, the Vietnamese people from the North sometimes say the ones from the South use wrong grammar.

@StuartF, most people working in nail industry in the USA say "round fingernails". If you say "rounded fingernails", they might think you are too grammatically technical. No one says like that.

@Tom  I will treat your questions as questions about the language not as questions about a particular industry.  If you want to talk nails, try salons.stackexchange.com
